# Vector interpolation returns same value

Tags: matlab, vector, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a pair of simulated points `qmu` and `qy` by using the Y-axis coordinates of experimental data `qL_nw`. So the idea is to lock the Y values and find the X correspondent in my simulated data. Although, I receive the error message that there are too many duplicates in my values, I arranged that by using `[qmu, qy] = unique(qmu,'stable');` so it works. The problem is that doesn't matter which interpolation method I use or I get the same value for the entire vector or I get NaN and some repeated values at the end. So far my code is:

```
[qmu, qy] = unique(qmu,'stable');    %Excluding duplicate numbers
iq5_2 = interp1(qy/h,qmu/max(qmu),qL_nw,'linear');
```

All variables are vectors.

So far `linear` returns all NaN, `pchip` repeated values and `nearest` partial NaN and end of repeated values. I can't find the error in this code, can someone help me with it?

---

In simple words:

I have a pair of vectors `Xs` and `Ys` and a third vector `Ye` and I want to find an interpolated `X` vector based on `Ys` and `Ye`. Although the results doesn't make sense no matter the interpolation method, or it goes all Nan or has the same values along the vector, with this code:

```
Xs = [1 2 3 4];
Ys = [0.5 0.8 1.3 1.8];
Ye = [0 0.5 1 2];
[Xs, Ys] = unique(Xs,'stable');
Xinterpolated = interp1(Ys,Xs,Ye,'linear');
```

The purpose of all this is to compare two sources (`Xs,Ys` and `Xe,Ye`) so I can find standard deviation and rmse.

Comment: Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem (that is, define `qmu`, `qy` etc). Otherwise it is hard for anyone to guess what the problem is

Comment: Removing duplicates is not enough, the function you are trying to interpolate needs to be a valid scalar function (each value of x has a single value of y). Swapping x and y in your data usually leads to a function where this is not the case. You can only swap x and y if the function is strictly monotonic (as in your example, where `unique` is not necessary, and completely changes `Ys` to be meaningless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that my vectors weren't sorted. I applied the sort function to the pair `Xs and Yx` and it worked fine. It wasn't necessary to remove duplicates with `unique`. Thank you for all the replies. For those in the future that might have the same problem the sorting code was:

```
[Ys, aux] = sort(Ys);
Xs = Xs(aux);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extrapolate outside the Xs,Ys input range. Try this:

```
xinterpol = interp1(Ys,Xs,Ye,'linear','extrap');
```

[image]